# height: 100% shrinks child in flexbox when another child increases the parent's height

Tags: html, css

I'm wondering why setting `height: 100%` decreases `.nav` height if there is another child who increases the parent's flexbox height, i.e. `.menu`

```css
.parent {
  border: 3px solid red;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}
.icon {
  height: 3em;
}
.menu {
  border: 2px solid green;
}
.nav {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  height: 100%;
 }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="icon"></div>
    <div class="text">MENU</div>
  </div>
  <div class="nav">
    <a>Home</a>
    <a>Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Presumably it interferes with the normal `stretch` behavior of flex layout.